# Bid Ask data merging based on same time-stamp of the historical tick data downloaded from Bloomberg

Tags: r, vba, bloomberg

The sample file as downloaded from Bloomberg is as follows (a), (b). the resulting file should be as (c). Please help with some R code or Excel or VBA code.
PS: if two timestamps are same then highest price should be taken and then priority should be given to size.

```
(a) TCS IN Equity       
01-04-2015 09:00:00 BID 2515    1
01-04-2015 09:00:04 BID 2553.95 133
01-04-2015 09:00:04 BID 2553.95 168
01-04-2015 09:00:06 BID 2515    1
01-04-2015 09:00:14 BID 2520    5
01-04-2015 09:00:24 BID 2525    3

(b)TCS IN Equity        
01-04-2015 09:00:00 ASK 2594    5
01-04-2015 09:00:04 ASK 2565    1
01-04-2015 09:00:05 ASK 2594    5
01-04-2015 09:00:14 ASK 2570    10
01-04-2015 09:05:28 ASK 2560    5

(c)
TCS IN Equity       BID BID_SIZ OFR OFR_SIZ
01-04-2015 09:00:00 2515    1   2594    5
01-04-2015 09:00:04 2553.95 168 2565    1
01-04-2015 09:00:14 2520    5   2570    10
```

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data along with the expected result _and_ the process that generates it?

Comment: Dear this intraday tick data is downloaded from Bloomberg in excel format. The data points shown here are very small. Actually the data points are very large around 10k to 15 k. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
A <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                           .Label = "01-04-2015", class = "factor"), 
                    time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
                           .Label = c("09:00:00", 
                                      "09:00:04", "09:00:06", "09:00:14", 
                                      "09:00:24"), class = "factor"), 
                    type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                           .Label = "BID", class = "factor"), 
                    BID = c(2515, 2553.95, 2553.95, 2515, 2520, 2525),
                    BID_SIZ = c(1L, 133L, 168L, 1L, 5L, 3L)), 
                    .Names = c("date", "time", "type", "BID", "BID_SIZ"),
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
B <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                           .Label = "01-04-2015", class = "factor"), 
                    time = structure(1:5, 
                           .Label = c("09:00:00", "09:00:04", 
                                      "09:00:05", "09:00:14", "09:05:28"),
                            class = "factor"), 
                    type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                           .Label = "ASK", class = "factor"), 
                    OFR = c(2594L, 2565L, 2594L, 2570L, 2560L), 
                    OFR_SIZ = c(5L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 5L)), 
                    .Names = c("date", "time", "type", "OFR", "OFR_SIZ"),
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(A, B, by = c("date", "time")) %>% 
     group_by(date, time) %>% 
     arrange(BID, BID_SIZ)  %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(last)) %>%
     select(-type.x, -type.y)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
# Groups: date
# 
#         date     time     BID BID_SIZ  OFR OFR_SIZ
# 1 01-04-2015 09:00:00 2515.00       1 2594       5
# 2 01-04-2015 09:00:04 2553.95     168 2565       1
# 3 01-04-2015 09:00:14 2520.00       5 2570      10
```

**Explanation**

First, you use `inner_join` to join the two data sets together. Then, you sort within each `date/time` combination according to `BID/BID_SIZ`and then you select the last row.

Comment: Dear, the data shown here is just sample. Actually there are around 15000 bid and ask points. So it is difficult to access data through list or structure.

Comment: Don't get you comment. If you can organize your two data sets as `data.frame` the code shown above will work. Did you give it a try? If so, what was the error code, if not, why not?